# Passing typedefed two-dimensional array of structs as function argument

Tags: c, arrays, struct, arduino, typedef

TL;DR;
The problem was I forgot to write a prototype for a function. Adding this fixed the issue:

```
void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure);
```

Full text:

I write a tetris clone for Arduino.
In my implementation, I have a `struct` representing a point on screen:

```
struct tt_point
{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Each figure is an array of its rotation 'snaphots' or 'frames'. Each frame is an array of `tt_points`, which makes a figure a two-dimensional array of `tt_points` (you may find it ugly, but the question is not about design).

I'd like to typedef this two dimensional array and pass it to a function. Here is the typedef I have:

```
typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4];
```

And a 'T' figure:

```
tt_figure tt_T = {
    {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2},
            {1,1}},

           {{0,1}, 
     {1,0}, {1,1},
            {2,1}},

           {{0,1}, 
     {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}},

    {{0,0}, 
     {1,0}, {1,1},
     {2,0}}
    };
```

Problems begin when I try to pass a figure to a function:

```
void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure) { ... }
```

The error is:

```
Tetris:20: error: variable or field 'tt_drawFigure' declared void
Tetris:20: error: 'tt_figure' was not declared in this scope
```

How should I rewrite the declaration to pass a `tt_figure` to a function?

P.S. I made it working by declaring a figure as `void*` and then casting to 4x4 array:

```
void tt_drawFigure(void* figure)
{
  tt_point * fig = ((tt_point(*)[4]) figure)[frame_index];
  ...
}
```

But there should be a nicer way.

UPDATE.
The code you can copy, paste and try to compile:

```
struct tt_point
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4];

tt_figure tt_T = {
{{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2},
        {1,1}},

       {{0,1}, 
 {1,0}, {1,1},
        {2,1}},

       {{0,1}, 
 {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}},

{{0,0}, 
 {1,0}, {1,1},
 {2,0}}
};


void setup()
{

}


void loop()
{

}

void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure)
{

}
```

Comment: I feel that there are some braces missing. You really should format your arrays properly.

Comment: The workaround is not just ugly, but very bad practice. Never use `void *` unless it is the only and best way (it most times is none).

Comment: And again: [mcve] missing. Next!

Comment: The workaround should be unnecessary.  But we can't see why your code makes it necessary — you've not shown us a fragment that produces just the error you show.  You need to show us code that when copied and pasted into a source file will reproduce the error you see.

Comment: @Olaf the string void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure) { ... } exactly follows the rule from your example. Still no luck.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The array is formatted properly, no braces are missed. I have a running project on a board.

Comment: Are you sure you have `typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4];` and not `typedef struct tt_point tt_figure[4][4];` ?

Comment: @dbush yes, I have typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4]

Comment: `try.c:7:9: error: unknown type name ‘tt_point’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles if you change:

`typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4];` to

`typedef struct tt_point tt_figure[4][4];`.

For example this code below compiles and runs fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct tt_point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

/* typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4]; /*  /* Issue here */
typedef struct tt_point tt_figure[4][4]; /* add `struct' to typedef */

void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure);

tt_figure tt_T = { {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,1}},
                   {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},{2,1}},
                   {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},{1,2}},
                   {{0,0}, {1,0},{1,1}, {2,0}}
                 };

int main(void)
{
    tt_drawFigure(tt_T);
    return 0;
}

void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure)
{ 
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    printf("%d, %d --- ", figure[i][j].x, figure[i][j].y);
            printf("\n");
    }
    /* Do your drawing */
}
```

---

You can also do

```
typedef struct tt_point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} tt_figure[4][4];
```

so that you don't accidentally miss `struct` - like you missed when you did a `typedef` separately.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was I forgot the prototype(?) of a function:

`typedef struct tt_point tt_figure[4][4];
void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure);`

Adding `void tt_drawFigure(tt_figure figure);` did the trick.

Comment: I found that the keyword `struct` was unnecessary. Even `typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4];` compiles fine (Maybe some arduino-flavour of C?).

Comment: @AndreySolovyov Are you using C++?

Comment: well, the `struct` keyword is necessary - unluess you have typedef'd tt_point before. Which compliler are you using.

Comment: @sps, melpomene: shame on me, but I do not know. I am using that green default arduino ide.

Comment: @sps Could you also please explain, why when I access array's elements even by hardcoded indices, I got them in reverse order? `figure[0]`, `figure[1]`, `figure[2]`, `figure[3]` gives me last, third, second and first elements respectively.

Comment: its not clear what you are saying. I think its better if you ask a new question for your new issue, as more people will look into it. If you insist on continuing this comment, please explain your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not syntactically correct:

```
typedef tt_point tt_figure[4][4];
```

Unless you previously created a `typedef` for `tt_point`, this will fail to compile.  What you want is this:

```
typedef struct tt_point tt_figure[4][4];
```

The `struct` keyword is required anywhere the struct type is used.  If you do this, the example code compiles cleanly.